# Remove Outlier Value from Text File

Tags: unix, awk, statistics

I need to detect and remove an outlier from a text file in Linux, perhaps using a standard deviation of some kind?

**vals.txt**

```
57
60.95
61
66.80
74.42 <--- OUTLIER/BAD DATA
```

After this, I need to calculate the mean value from the column.

**ATTEMPTED CODE**

```
awk '{
cnt[$1]++
val[$1] = (val[$1] ? val[$1] "," $1 : $1)
sum[$1] += $1
    } END {
for (i in val) {
    n = split(val[i], a, " ")
    for (k=1; k<=n; k++)
        if (!((sqrt((a[k] - (sum[i]/cnt[i]))^2)) < ((sum[i] / cnt[i]) * (30/100)))) {
            cnt[i]--
            sum[i] -= val[i]
        }
}
for (i in sum)
    printf "%8.5f   %6.2f   %6d   %6.3f\n", i, sum[i], cnt[i], sum[i] / cnt[i] | "sort -nk1"
}' vals.txt
```

Comment: Why is 74.42 an outlier and 57 not?

Comment: `grep -v OUTLIER file` should solve the problem with current information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, so I'm going to make an assumption that an outlier is more than one standard deviation from the overall mean (Which would also exclude 57), and that the mean of all non-outlying values is the one you want at the end.

(The following uses [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to do the number crunching because I don't feel like looking up the (population) standard deviation formula and calculating it in awk)

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { low = $1 - $2; high = $1 + $2; next }
       $1 >= low && $1 <= high { sum += $1; count += 1 }
       END { print sum / count }' <(datamash mean 1 pstdev 1 < vals.txt) vals.txt
62.9167
```

If these assumptions are wrong, fix your question to reflect what you're using as a definition of outlier, and what your want the results to look like given your sample data, and I'll update or delete this as appropriate.